# 3.5mm Audio extension

Tags: audio, hub, audio-adapters

One of my friends has problems with the 3.5mm audio jacks on the front of his PC. He's not technical enough to look into fixing those and what that implies. With lockdown all over the place, it's hard to go to a specialised shop right now, so we want an alternative to make this work.

The audio jacks on the back of the case work well, but the headphones cable is not long enough to allow to sit comfortably at the desk.  I would like something like a little hub (mc+headphones) he could connect to the back of his PC and leverage those ports via this extension.

We looked at a few things but some were not what we were after:

1. [Desktop adapter for specific desks with the round hole cutouts](https://www.amazon.co.uk/CSL-recessed-Built-Connector-Microphone-black/dp/B07H4MYS4C/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=desktop%20audio&qid=1589208613&sr=8-3) This one only works if you have those corner holes in your desktop, so not great a great fit.
2. [Front Panel](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07SQ17YD7/ref=sspa_dk_detail_7?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B07SQ17YD7&pd_rd_w=35Cj9&pf_rd_p=1055d8b2-c10c-4d7d-b50d-96300553e15d&pd_rd_wg=9QwnN&pf_rd_r=E04H8QMAQ20V5CYVT26B&pd_rd_r=45836c56-c391-4c7d-b68f-44ec1031709e&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyQTdDOU04WkJaTUNRJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMzc3Mzg2M0RDVjlGNE1HV1haQiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwOTE1NzQ4MjFJUUlZQTE3STY5UCZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2RldGFpbCZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=) The person can't be trusted to open the case and install this since they have no experience with this.
3. USB to 3.5 mm not really excited about, they are usually short and the 1 working front USB port is used for other stuff.
4. [Creative Sound - Desktop audio control module](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Creative-Blaster-Performance-Headphone-Desktop/dp/B00A152RYG/ref=sr_1_19?dchild=1&keywords=desktop%20audio&qid=1589208613&sr=8-19) Something like this module would be nice, but without the entire card since opening the case is not an option.
5. I have one of these hubs on my keyboard, but his keyboard does not have one, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6) How about a 3.5mm male-3.5mm female four pole TRRS (tip-ring-ring-sleeve) extension cord?

The four pole is needed since it's a headset, not just headphones (which only need three pole, tip-ring-sleeve). Examples shown at https://www.google.com/search?psb=1&tbm=shop&q=3.5mm%20headset%20extension%20cable .

Please confirm the plug on the end of his headset looks like the plug shown in those pix.

Comment: This seems to be the only way. We put 2 extensions together and it seems to work fine.